# How to add a key similar to key '_id' in the mongoDB default key list?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In mongoDB, whenever we try on insert any document, mongoDB appends a key '_id' known as ObjectId. I am looking for something similar and trying to replicate the scenario.
In my case, I am trying to create a key as 'hash' whose value could be generated based on some calculations with respect to documents values.

Let's say I'm using db as stuff

```
> use stuff
```

Inserting document

```
> db.products.insert( { item: "card", qty: 15 } )
```

So usually mongoDB will add ObjectId and store it as

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5063114bd386d8fadbd6b004"), "item" : "card", "qty"
> : 15 }

But I'm trying to store document as something like this

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5063114bd386d8fadbd6b004"), "hash" :
> "51e0373c6f35bd826f47e9a1", "item" : "card", "qty" : 15 }

Is there a way to add a custom key in the mongoDB default key list or any other way to implement above scenario without inserting it along with document explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field is actually created in the driver code on the client side and submitted with the document.

So you could certainly add a client-side middleware function to add whatever field you like.